# Recursive generics and Array inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a few generic recursive types to modify structure of existing types. I can't tell why the sections inferring arrays and nested objects is not getting triggered. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[TS playround link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-4a9bA0GKmibO2653G30SeCIYC9NBrcJqUCrVne5W6gCsAAZcwAaVna+3WzUJJKpdLpm3hnU-CAAdyZOQgAAoAJQFqDFACiokItFZ8szJqoecLw6BRflxhn044cYIJF1crrpYARABGABMAGYN-O3h8x1At-n53PHNYZIIawqT76qAAWC-FiNUfpTtfypz8Vxqn4Za1iWurbvuh5TiOj5wuOb61leFqIesSyXkWwJAA) with the below code:

```js
//Generics
type WithConfidence<T> = {
  [Property in keyof T]: {
    value: FieldWithConfidence<T[Property]>;
    confidence: number;
  };
};

type FieldWithConfidence<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string | number | Date
    ? T[P]
    : T[P] extends Array<infer U>
    ? {
        confidence: number;
        value: Array<WithConfidence<U>>;
      }
    : {
        value: FieldWithConfidence<T[P]>;
        confidence: number;
      };
};
```

It works for primitive types and when the type is an object, just not an array. Here's an example illustrating where it falls short.

```
type Asset = {
  AssetCode?: string;
  Contracts?: Array<Contract>;
  Warranty: WarrantyInfo;
};

type Contract = {
  ContractNumber: string;
};

type WarrantyInfo = {
  Purchased: Date;
};

const value: WithConfidence<Asset> = {
  Warranty: {
    confidence: 500,
    value: {
      Purchased: {
        value: new Date(), //Error
        confidence: 500,
      },
    },
  },
  AssetCode: {
    value: "123",
    confidence: 100,
  },
  Contracts: {
    confidence: 400,
    value: [
      {
        ContractNumber: { //Error
          value: "123",
          confidence: 500,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I have most of an answer ready, but I need to clarify one aspect: in your "Target" comment, you show each item in the `Contracts` array being an object with a plain `ContractNumber` property (not turned into a confidence-value object itself), but with a `confidence` property alongside that property. However, in your sample data, you have `ContractNumber` turned into a confidence-value object, consistent with the rest of the pattern. I assume you intend the latter?

Comment: You are correct. I'm going to update the question with an updated TS playground to remove that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what I mentioned in my comment on your question, the fix is just to simplify your `FieldWithConfidence` type significantly. Right now it is trying to add a number of additional levels of structure beyond what you seem to want. Here is a version of that type that works as I think you intend:

```
type FieldWithConfidence<T> =
  T extends boolean | string | number | Date
    ? T
    : T extends Array<infer U>
      ? Array<FieldWithConfidence<U>>
      : WithConfidence<T>;
```

[Here's a working playground link with that change.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Kvs4uqC2O12V5Pc-3PT7j0Du6Xu0tC2XQcUuipmEgioUoKFFi+kH1isGq2AIhSAoLB-2zA0AwoAIKXYcDsynV0aX+OCPxVMt4JwddxzAtCENPfZkN8VCIMgo1l0w0jcNI7NsM3f5oPJFhfUomiewIigiNod82NLHiIKWfj1gwvClBUCIHWoiDELzLiWNE4M9yktiEiSVJ0lAoTePrKCUxI7T1hk74uP0tjjC0osLPM-9zKAA)